# Angular2 : how to set Validators.required as common validation for 2 fields

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I am using Angular2 ForumBulder to create form and to add validations.  Below the sample code from component

```
this.OtpForm = this._fb.group({
    otpInput: this._fb.group({
      otpInput1: ['', Validators.required],
      otpInput2: ['', Validators.required],
      otpInput3: ['', Validators.required],
    }, { validator: this.numericValidator })
});
```

Now this works fine. But question is how to `Validators.required` as common to all the field  just like custom validator `numericValidator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create one more custom validator for otpInput group, for example

```
validateAllRequired(g: FormGroup) {
    let ctrls = g.controls;
    let keys = Object.keys(ctrls);
    let valid = true;
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      let ctrl = ctrls[key];
      if (ctrl.value.trim() == '') {
        valid = false;
      }
    });
    return valid ? null : {
      validateAllRequired: {
        valid: valid
      }
    };
}
```

and add to this:

```
otpInput: this._fb.group({
  otpInput1: [''],
  otpInput2: [''],
  otpInput3: [''],
}, { validator: Validators.compose([this.numericValidator, this.validateAllRequired]) })
```

combine validators using Validators.compose()

```
Validators.compose([...])
```

for async validators use

```
Validators.composeAsync([...])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think `validateAllRequired`  needs to be referred as `this.validateAllRequired`. correct ??

Comment: if you defined `validateAllRequired` in current class, you need using `this`, otherwise you could defined in some where else to re-use this function, you do not need `this`, I'm recommend put your custom validation in other file, so you could import this function to use it.

Comment: Since the component in question is common one, so i though to keep function in the current class itself.  Now i have another issue that when i attach both custom validator like `{ validator: [this.numericValidator, this.validateAllRequired] }`, then i am getting error : `this.validator is not a function`.  Any suggestion on this error ??

Comment: check my update post, using Validators.compose to group multiple validators.

Comment: Thank you so much, it resolved that problem.  Still not getting desired result, I will try to debug.

Comment: hey guy, I made an update for correct trim space, please test it.

Comment: Yup it working fine now. Just one last question. i.e how to access that flag returned by the `validateAllRequired` in component HTML to show / hide errors ??

Comment: you can access through `errors` object `errors.validateAllRequired && errors.validateAllRequired.valid == false`

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks :-)